# Как сохранить изображение в галерее

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-permissions

В общем есть у меня простая рисовалка. Можно рисовать простые фигуры на canvas, и сохранять полученный результат в галерею в папку Pictures. Вот именно с сохранением и возникают проблемы.  На андроид 5 и ниже все работает хорошо, а вот начиная с 6 и выше сохранить картинку не получается, нет доступа к внутреннему хранилищу. Читал где что данная проблема связана с тем, что в андроид 6 изменилась модель разрешений для доступа к файловой системе. Но решения я так и не нашел. В манифесте прописано разрешение на запись в `EXTERNAL STORAGE`. При попытке сохранить картинку на андроиде выше 6 (Пробовал на реальном устройстве с андроид 7, и на эмуляторе с 6) в логах пишет `permission denied`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед сохранением изображения Вам нужно проверить, разрешен ли приложению доступ к карте памяти на запись. Если доступ разрешен, то все ок, если нет – то необходимо запросить это разрешение у пользователя:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        // Здесь отображаете диалог с объяснением -- зачем
        // Вашему приложению требуется данное разрешение.
        // По кнопке "Ок" диалога запрашиваете разрешение.

    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Далее, в методе `onRequestPermissionsResult(...)` получаете решение пользователя:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Пользователь разрешил доступ
                // Сохраняете картинку на диск

            } else {

                // Пользователь запретил доступ
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Более подробную информацию можно найти в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).